# how to create years range in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to create a drop down view to enable users to select their date of birth. I already finished building the component using  dummy data, but How can i implement data module for years / month / days using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) ?

What I am done so far , i build the drop down and work very well what i struggle with how can i replace the dummy data with real date data?

dropdown component :

```
const days = [
  { num: '1', key: '1' },
  { num: '2', key: '2' },
  { num: '3 ', key: '3' },
  { num: '4', key: '4' },
  { num: '5 ', key: '5' },
];

const Dropdown = ({ label, data }) => {
  const [selecteday, setSelecteday] = useState({ item: '' });

  const DropdownButton = useRef();
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

 

  const toggleFunction = () => {
    visible ? setVisible(false) : openDropdown();
  };

  const openDropdown = () => {
  
    setVisible(true);
  };

  const onItemPress = item => {
    setSelecteday(item);
    console.log(item);
    setVisible(false);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item} onPress={() => onItemPress(item)}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{item.num}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
  const renderDropdown = () => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.dropdown}>
        <FlatList
          data={days}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  };
  return (
    <>
    <View style={{zIndex: 10}} >
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => toggleFunction()}
        ref={DropdownButton}
        style={styles.button}
      >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
          {' '}
          {selecteday.item === '' ? label : selecteday.num}
        </Text>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="chevron-down" color={'#58abc8'} size={16} />
        {visible == true ? renderDropdown() : null}
      </TouchableOpacity>

    
      </View>
        { visible ? <View 
                 style={styles.modal}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                 style ={styles.overlay}
                 onPress={toggleFunction}
                 ></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>: null}
   </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting Days, Months and Years you can create functions like this

```
const getDays = (month, year) => {
        if (month <= 12 && month >= 1) {
            const daysCount = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
            console.log('daysCount--', daysCount);
            const daysAr = Array(daysCount).fill('').map((element, index) => {
                return {
                    key: index + 1 + '',
                    num: index + 1,
                }
            })
            console.log(daysAr);
        }
    }

    const getMonth = () => {
        const monthCount = 12; //this is always 12 so can pass static
        const monthsAr = Array(monthCount).fill('').map((element, index) => {
            return {
                key: index + 1 + '',
                num: index + 1,
            }
        })
        console.log(monthsAr);
    }

    const getYears = () => {
        const yeasCount = 200;//you can pass more then 200
        const yearsAr = Array(yeasCount).fill('').map((element, index) => {
            return {
                key: 1900 + index + '',
                num: 1900 + index,
            }
        })
        console.log(yearsAr);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        const selectedMonth = 5;
        const selectedYear = 2022;
        getMonth();
        getYears();
        getDays(selectedMonth, selectedYear); //first select year, month and pass selected month and year here.
    }, [])
```

**So you have to select year then month and then according of your selected month you will get days in month and convert into required array**